# Letters are not getting added to my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a hangman game which is working fine except one part.

I have two arrays, one to show the word to be guessed and add the letter of that word if guessed correct and the second is a array that spells out hangman letter by letter if a guess is wrong

The your  word array is working fine,However I cant find a way of adding letters to the hangman array if guess is wrong

```
playgame('Hello')

//output
/*yourword array*/
H _ _ _ _
/*Hangman array
H _ _ _ _ _ _
```

If I guess 'b' it should add the the next letter hangman to the hangman arrAy since 'b' is not in 'Hello'

If I guess 'e' it should add an e to yourword array since 'e' is in 'hello'

```js
function playgame(yourword) {
  //yourword array
  /*********************/
  let word = yourword.toUpperCase();
  let letters = word.split("");
  var answerArray = [letters[0]];
  for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
  }
  let answer = answerArray.join();

  //hangman array
  /*********************/
  let hgm = ["H", "A", "N", "G", "M", "A", "N"];
  let hgArray = [hgm[0]];
  for (var i = 1; i < hgm.length; i++) {
    hgArray[i] = "_";
  }
  //loop
  let remainingLetters = word.length - 1; // First letter is visible by default
  let remainingLetter = hgm.length;
  while (remainingLetters > 0 && remainingLetter > 0) {

    //show the array
    console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());

    let guess = prompt("guess a letter").toUpperCase();
    //add a letter if guessed correctly
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      if (word[i] === guess) {
        answerArray[i] = guess;
        remainingLetters--;
      }
      //add a letter to the hangman string if guessed incorrecty 
      //MY PROBLEM IS HERE

      if (word.indexOf(guess) === -1) {
        remainingLetter--;
      }

    }
    console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());
    if (remainingLetters === 0) {
      console.log("you win");
    } else if (remainingLetters !== 0) {
      console.log("you lose");
    }
  }
}

playgame('Hello');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the script to add letters to second array

```
function playgame(yourword) {
    //yourword array
    /*********************/
    let word = yourword.toUpperCase();
    let letters = word.split("");
    var answerArray = [letters[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
        answerArray[i] = "_";
    }
    let answer = answerArray.join();

    //hangman array
    /*********************/
    let hgm = ["H", "A", "N", "G", "M", "A", "N"];
    let hgArray = [hgm[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < hgm.length; i++) {
        hgArray[i] = "_";
    }
    //loop
    let remainingLetters = word.length - 1; // First letter is visible by default
    let remainingLetter = hgm.length - 1;
    while (remainingLetters > 0 && remainingLetter > 0) {

        //show the array
        console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
        console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());
        let isGuessCorrect = false
        let guess = prompt("guess a letter").toUpperCase();
        //add a letter if guessed correctly
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            if (word[i] === guess) {
                answerArray[i] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
                isGuessCorrect = true;
            }
            //add a letter to the hangman string if guessed incorrecty
            //MY PROBLEM IS HERE

            if (word.indexOf(guess) === -1) {
                console.log("Guees ---- " + remainingLetter)
                remainingLetter--;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!isGuessCorrect) {
            for (var i = 0; i < hgArray.length; i++) {
                if (hgArray[i] == "_") {
                    hgArray[i] = hgm[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
        console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());
        if (remainingLetter === 0 || remainingLetters === 0)
            break;
    }
    if (remainingLetters === 0) {
        console.log("you win");
    } else if (remainingLetters !== 0) {
        console.log("you lose");
    }

}
```

Sample Output :

```
H _ _ _ _
H,_,_,_,_,_,_
Guees ---- 6
H _ _ _ _
H,A,_,_,_,_,_
H _ _ _ _
H,A,_,_,_,_,_
Guees ---- 5
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,_,_,_,_
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,_,_,_,_
Guees ---- 4
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,_,_,_
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,_,_,_
Guees ---- 3
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,M,_,_
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,M,_,_
Guees ---- 2
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,M,A,_
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,M,A,_
Guees ---- 1
H _ _ _ _
H,A,N,G,M,A,N
you lose
```

Comment: If HANGMAN is spelt out it does not log 'you lose'